# UI test with mocha and coffee script

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver, coffeescript

I am setting up test case environment with the help of [Getting started with Selenium WebDriver for node.js](https://team.goodeggs.com/getting-started-with-selenium-webdriver-for-node-js-f262a00c52e1)

I have installed all dependencies but still unable to run sample test case given in above blog:

```
selenium = require 'selenium-webdriver'
chai = require 'chai'
chai.use require 'chai-as-promised'
expect = chai.expect

before ->
    @timeout 10000
@driver = new selenium.Builder()
    .withCapabilities(selenium.Capabilities.chrome())
    .build()
@driver.getWindowHandle()

after ->
    @driver.quit()

describe 'Webdriver tutorial', ->
beforeEach ->
    @driver.get 'http://bites.goodeggs.com/posts/selenium-webdriver-nodejs-tutorial/'

it 'has the title of the post in the window\'s title', ->
expect(@driver.getTitle()).to.eventually.contain
'Getting started with Selenium Webdriver for node.js'

it 'has publication date', ->
text = @driver.findElement(css: '.post .meta time').getText()
expect(text).to.eventually.equal 'December 30th, 2014'

it 'links back to the homepage', ->
@driver.findElement(linkText: 'Bites').click()
expect(@driver.getCurrentUrl()).to.eventually.equal 'http://bites.goodeggs.com/'
```

Running above test case with:

```
mocha JavaScript_test.coffee  --compilers coffee:coffee-script/register
```

I get following error:

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'coffee-script/register'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:337:3
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/mocha/bin/_mocha:329:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I don't know when it change but the module coffee-script doesn't exist anymore.
The right package is ***coffeescript*** so the right command is :

```
mocha JavaScript_test.coffee  --compilers coffee:coffeescript/register
```

But  [--compilers is deprecated](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/compilers-deprecation) so the new right syntaxe is :

```
mocha JavaScript_test.coffee  --require coffeescript/register
```